# What is the equivalent of $f$ when $x$ approaches $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

> $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \ln(n).x^n$
>
> $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} a_n.x^n $, such that: $ a_1=-1$ and $a_n=-\ln \big(1 - \frac{1}{n} \big) - \frac{1}{n} $ for $n \ge 2$.
>
> 1. Prove that: $g(x) = (1 -x)f(x) + \ln(1-x) $.
> 2. We admit that $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln n$ converges toward $\alpha$. (Euler constant). Compute $g(1)$ and find en equivalent of $f$ near $1$.
> 3. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ converge and $\sum_{k=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = \ln2$
> 4. Using the formula: $n! \sim (\frac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$, compute $g(-1)$.
> 5. Deduce $\lim_{x\to -1} f(x)$.

---

1. I have proved that: $ g(x) = (1-x)f(x) + \ln (1 -x) $
2. $$
   \begin{align}
   g(1)
   & = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \\ 
   & = a_1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} a_n \\
   & = -1 + \sum_{k=2}^n  -\ln \big(1 - \frac{1}{k} \big) - \frac{1}{k} \\ 
   & = -1 + \ln(n) - \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k}  \\
   & = - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln n\\
   & = - \alpha
   \end{align}
   $$

For the equivalent, I need to find a function $h(x) $such that $\lim \frac{f(x)}{h(x)} = 1$ when $x$ approaches $1$ which I don't know how to do.

3. I am stuck in the second part of proving the serie converges to $\ln 2$, How can I do it?
4. I could not see the link between the given formula and the value of $g(-1)$. How can I compute it?
5. I think I will find it from the equation $ g(x) = (1-x)f(x) + \ln (1 -x) $ once I will know the value of $g(-1)$ which I don't know how to do.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First $g(1)$ does not equal to what you wrote. Still your result is good.
2. Just use the previous result :

$$
f\left(x\right)=\frac{g\left(x\right)}{1-x}-\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{1-x}
$$
Hence
$$
f\left(x\right)\frac{x-1}{\ln(1-x)}=\frac{g(x)}{\ln(1-x)}+1 \underset{x \rightarrow 1}{\rightarrow}1
$$
Hence
$$
f\left(x\right) \underset{(1)}{\sim}\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x-1}
$$
3. A beautiful trick is to consider the partial sum and remark that

$$
\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^n=\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\left(-x\right)^{n-1}\text{d}x
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\int_{0}^{1}\left(-x\right)^{n-1}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(-x\right)^{n-1}\text{d}x
$$
So
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\left(-x\right)^{N-1}}{1+x}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-x\right)^{n-1}}{1+x}\text{d}x$$

The second integral satisfies
$$
\left|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-x\right)^{n-1}}{1+x}\text{d}x\right| \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}\underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
Letting $n \rightarrow +\infty$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x}=\ln(2)$$

4. You have
   $$
   g\left(-1\right)=-\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\left(-1\right)^k\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)+\ln(2)
   $$

Let $\displaystyle S_N=\sum_{k=2}^{N}\left(-1\right)^k\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)$
You have
$$
S_{2N}=\sum_{k=2}^{2N}\left(-1\right)^k\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)
$$
hence
$$
S_{2N}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln(2k-1)-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln(2k)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln(2k)+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln(2k+1)  $$
Regrouping we have
$$
S_{2N}=2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln(2k+1)-2\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln(2k)+\ln(2N)$$

Then you have
$$
e^{S_{2N}}=\frac{1}{2N}\left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{N-1}2k+1}{\prod_{k=1}^{N-1}2k}\right)^2=2N\frac{\left(2N\right)!^2}{\left(2^NN!\right)^4}
$$

Now apply Stirling formula as it is written we got
$$2N\frac{\left(2N\right)!^2}{\left(2^NN!\right)^4} \underset{N\rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{2}{\pi}$$
And

> $$
> g\left(-1\right)=-\ln(\frac{2}{\pi})+\ln(2)=\ln\left(\pi\right)
> $$

If i havent made too much mistakes lol

5.
$$
f\left(-1\right)\underset{(-1)}{\sim}\frac{g(-1)}{2}-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}=\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)
$$

Comment: 1. Is the answer of my first question false? 

2. I could not get the equivalent of $f$ using the fraction because $1-x$ approaches zero when $x$ approaches 1. Could you elaborate more please ? 

3. I could not notice that, thank you so much. 

4. What about $g(-1)$?

Comment: I'm writing it, the 4. question is long xD, the answer is correct however g(1) is not a partial sum, in fact u calculate a sequence that will converge to g(1).

Comment: I think $g(-1) = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \ln(1 - \frac{1}{k}) - \frac{1}{k}$ No?

Comment: Why would it be a finite sum ?

Comment: I meant $ \sum_{k=2}^{+ \infty} \ln(1 - \frac{1}{k}) - \frac{1}{k}$, I thought you forgot the $\frac{1}{k}$ ?

Comment: It's not the definition of $g$ you gave me

Comment: I am so sorry, I made a made a mistake. I will edit it now, take a look again...

Comment: I edited it, I am sorry I forgot to type it.

Comment: No problem, what i've written is still correct, you will need after the final result to have your $\ln(2)$ adding to it

Comment: Why did you take $S_{2n}$? For $2n$?

Comment: To split into add an even to make the $(-1)^n$ vanish ( i'm looking at it, i think i've made a small mistake )

Comment: Could you please explain to me how $S_{2n} = S_{2N}=\sum_{k=2}^{2N}\left(-1\right)^k\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right) $? Thank you so much.

Comment: You split the even terms of the odd ones

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. =)

Comment: One last questions, the question 2, I could not really find the equivalent of using the equation $f(x) = \frac{g(x) - ln(1-x)}{x-1}$

Comment: Ok i will edit the post